# Finding moment of Inertia of area bounded by a polar equation

Tags: physics, graphing-functions, classical-mechanics

I have to find Moment of Inertia of area bounded by curve $r^2 = a^2 \cos{2 \Theta}$

Since I already know the shape of given curve, I can easily take an element area and double integrate using suitable values of $r$ and $\Theta$.

But is there any general method to follow, say in an examination, when I don't know what the curve of given polar equation looks like? Finding $r$ values corresponding to specific $\Theta$ seems time consuming.

Or, does there exist any method for finding Moment of Inertia which does not require plotting of curve?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: the curve $r^2=a^2\cos(2\theta)$ is the [lemniscate of Bernoulli](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html) in polar coordinates.

Comment: thanks but this does not answer my question whether there is a way to plot such curves by hand

Comment: @AbhishekRana Now yow know thaty the curve is a Lemniscate. This is a well known curve and you can find easily all about it. See [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=PSdWuoORYhEC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=how+to+draw+lemniscate+of+bernoulli+by+hand&source=bl&ots=BsGzGbgekJ&sig=45jgsvP9zYjj1Gemq8jIFl3Inlk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi89-aV6bTZAhWDy6QKHRnRACsQ6AEIXjAL#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20draw%20lemniscate%20of%20bernoulli%20by%20hand&f=false) for example.

Comment: But this is only one example. I am trying to figure out a general approach where, say in an exam, I am given a $r$ and $\Theta$ relation and I have to find Moment of Inertia of the curve. Is there a method to figure out what the curve looks like for any general polar equation?

Comment: @Abhishek Rana Then you should change your OP....